# In Visual Studio, how can I prevent my package for including other languages?

Tags: cordova, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2015

My app is being rejected because of unsupported languages, more specifically, "declares one or more unsupported languages". I don't need any language but english in the my app. How can I remove support so my app will upload to the store?

I building a Cordova Windows 8.1 app in Visual Studio.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff637520(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: I want to do the opposite. When I build it adds languages that I don't need/want.

Comment: I understand that, but that article covers every option related to localization, so you should be able to use it as a guide to figure out where the invalid data is coming from.

Comment: for example, what is listed when you check this step: "On the project’s Properties page, in the Supported Culture box, select the language(s) you would like your app to support."?

Comment: To be honest I don't see a "properties page".

Comment: your project in the solution panel doesn't have a properties option for it when you right click it?

Comment: Yes, but there's no option in there. Just one option regarding debugging

Comment: what about in the `package.appxmanifest` file?

Comment: doesn't have one. I do have an `Appmanifest.xml` file that I removed the languages from and left `en-us`

Comment: There's one under plantforms but when I remove the languages from that build `appmanifest.xml` file and rebuild it puts them back.

Comment: Under "view" `Property Pages` is grayed out...

Comment: I got the property pages to show but the option regarding culture isn't listed

Comment: I honestly don't know what might be the issue with your setup at this point, but I hope you are able to figure it out.